# Use cordova plugins in angular 6 application

Tags: angular, cordova, cordova-plugins

I transformed by angular application into a cordova application and I tried to use cordova plugins, but I couldn't make it work. For example I want to use this plugin in my angular application: https://github.com/leon/cordova-plugin-nowplaying. How can I use the NowPlaying.set function from my angular app?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the better option but I ususally -when I can use cordova pluging- use a "service" to store values or object. e.g. your main.app.ts can be like

```
//Use "declare" to have variables that store cordova and pluggins before Component declaration
declare var StatusBar: any;
declare var cordova: any;
declare var window:any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

//In constructor you inject a service (you can called cordovaService)
cosntructor(private cordovaService:CordovaService){}

//You must add in ngAfterViewInit a document.addEventListener('device ready')
ngAfterViewInit() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
  }
  onDeviceReady() {
    //Typical you use to defined aht happens when, pause, resume,backbutton..
    document.addEventListener('pause', this.onPause.bind(this), false);
    document.addEventListener('resume', this.onResume.bind(this), false);
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", this.onBackKeyDown.bind(this), false);

    //MoreOver you have there your "plugging"
    //for example, if add StatusBar pluging you have "StatusBar"
    //So you can
    StatusBar.hidden();
    //Or if you have a variable "StatusBar" in your service
    this.cordovaService.StatusBar=StatusBar
    //so, any component that inject "CordovaService" would make a
    //this.cordovaService.StatusBar.hide() or this.cordovaService.StatusBar.show() 

    //idem if you has imported getAppVersion, you can do
    cordova.getAppVersion.getVersionNumber().then(version => {
      console.log(version)
    });
    //Or make
    this.cordovaService.cordova=cordova
    //so, any component that inject "CordovaService" would make a
    //this.cordovaService.cordova.getAppVersion.getVersionNumber().then(version =>
    //  {
    //    console.log(version)
    //  });
}
```

In case of pluggin "now playing" I supouse you can adopt this "technica"